# using prisma, how do you access newly created record from within a nested write (update first, then create within)

Tags: javascript, prisma

Using [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/), I have a question about accessing a record that was newly created from within a nested write (update first, then create within).

I'm following along the examples on [this page in the prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries).

In particular, I am looking at the following two items in the data model:

Note, I have slightly modified the example for the purposes of this question by adding a `counter` to `User`.

```
model User {
  id       Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email    String  @unique
  posts    Post[]
  counter  Int
}
model Post {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  title      String
  author     User?    @relation(fields:  [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId   Int?
}
```

Now, let's say you want to create a new `Post` and connect it to the `User` and at the same time, you also want to increment the `counter`.

My assumption, after reading [this section of the doc](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#update-an-existing-user-record-by-creating-a-new-post-record) is that you would need to update the existing `User` and within that, create a new `Post` record.

i.e.

```
const user = await prisma.user.update({
  where: { email: 'alice@prisma.io' },
  data: {
    // increment the counter for this User
    counter: {
      increment: 1,
    },
    // create the new Post for this User
    posts: {
      create: { title: 'Hello World' },
    },
  },
})
```

My question is this. In the above scenario, how do you access the newly created `Post` in the return of the query?

In particular, say you want to get the `id` of the new `Post`?

From what I can tell, the returned `user` object could possibly include the array of all associated `Posts`, i.e. if you added this to the `update` query...

```
include: {
  posts: true,
}
```

But I can't yet see how, using Prisma, you get the individual `Post` that you just created as part of this `update` query.

Answer (score 1):

I have found one way of achieving this that works.

It uses [the `tranaction` api](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions#the-transaction-api).

Basically, instead of trying to use a nested write that begins with an update on `User` and contains a nested create on `Post`...

I split the two operations out into separate variables and run them together using a `prisma.$transaction()` as follows.

```js
const updateUser = prisma.user.update({
  where: { email: 'alice@prisma.io' },
  data: {
    // increment the counter for this User
    counter: {
      increment: 1,
    },
  },
});

const createPost = prisma.post.create({
  data: {
    // create the new Post for this User
    title: 'Hello World',
    author: {
      connect: {
        email: 'alice@prisma.io',
      },
    },
  },
});

const [ updateUserResult, createPostResult ] = await prisma.$transaction([updateUser, createPost ]);

// if createPostResult, then can access details of the new post from here...
```